# Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have a pyqt5 app and generate `.exe` file using `pyinstaller test.spec`(test is my project name). opening the `.exe` file in the dist folder works just fine. But when I try to open the app into another machine (virtual), it gives an import error:

```
Import Error: DLL load failed while importing _socket: The parameter is incorrect.

[1904] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing
```

I am lost and tried searching only to be more confused. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. And funnily enough, only when installing on certain computers, but not others.

Comment: @Erez Same for me...

Answer (score 2):

1. It's also a good idea to downgrade Python to 3.6
2. Must say that only solution is update windows 7 to sp1. If error still exist, on SP1 must be installed KB2533623 (reboot required) and vc_redist.x86.exe
   [pyinstaller/issues](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4706)

Answer (score 0):

I think your virtual machine's environment is different from your build environment. If it is possible, how about trying building on your virtual machine and open the app?

Comment: Hi! the Windows 7 installed in my virtual machine lacks updates hence causing the problem. I fixed it by updating the system. Thanks for the response